# How can I mathematically determine the next available index for a child row in this data set?

Tags: algorithms, data-analysis

I have a data set that looks like this:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
  & 0 & 1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9 \\
\hline
        parent & x & x & x & x &   &   & x &   &   &   \\
        child1 &   & x &   & x & x &   &   &   &   &   \\
        child2 &   & x & x &   & x & x &   &   &   &   \\
        child3 &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   &   &   \\
\end{array}
$$

An $x$ represents a data index that is defined somewhere else.

I need to know, for any $childN$, which is the first index that is not defined at both the parent **and** $childN$ level. How can I do this mathematically or logically?

In the above example, $child1$'s next available index is 5, $child2$'s next available index is 7, and $child3$'s next available index is 4.

Essentially I want to build an algorithm to determine the first available index for $childN$, according to the condition that I listed above (parent must not be defined at that index).

Comment: This looks more like a programming question, and would depend on particular language chosen. Make a matrix $A(n,m)$ where $A(1,:)$ is the parent and $A(i,:)$ is for child $i-1$. Initiate matrix $A$ by $0$, and replace each $x$ by $1$. Define $B(n,m)=A(1,m)+A(n,m)$. Now the first $m$ for which $B(n+1,m)=0$ is the available index for child $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let P and C be logical representations of Parent row and Child_N.  You're looking for the min non zero index of !Parent & !Child.  In MATLAB you can code it as follows

> > P=[1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0];
> >
> > C=[0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0];
> >
> > I=find(not(P) & not(C))

I =  6     8     9    10

> > min(I)

ans =  6

Note that array index starts with 1 in MATLAB, so 6 corresponds to your 5'th column index.